# PHP latest Docker image exits with code 0

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

Whenever I use `php:latest` Docker image, the container exits with a code 0 error, whereas, `php:7.4-fpm-alpine` image keeps the container running as expected. I didn't find a difference between the two `php:latest` and `php:7.4-fpm-alpine` images. I want to ensure that I always use the latest stable PHP version; I don't want to write a specific version number in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Here is the following `docker-compose.yml` file that I am using and shows the error:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "70:70"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:delegated
      - ./www:/var/www/html:delegated
  php:
    image: php:latest
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html:delegated
```

And here's the other one with PHP v7.4 FPM Alpine image that works just fine:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "70:70"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:delegated
      - ./www:/var/www/html:delegated
  php:
    image: php:7.4-fpm-alpine
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html:delegated
```

As you can see, both are identical `docker-compose.yml` files except for the PHP image change. Any idea what am I doing wrong? Why the `php:latest` docker image is exiting with a code 0 instead of running the container as `php:7.4-fpm-alpine` does?

Comment: you need `php-fpm` for connecting with `nginx`. try `php:fpm` for your image

Answer (score 0):

As I can surppose,It may because the diffrence of the `cmd` section between `php:latest` image and `php:74-fpm-alpine` image.
For information, run `docker inspect <container-name>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).